# Date time index sets wrong

Tags: python, datetime, indexing

I have a Dataframe called file, but the column `'Time valid (UTC)'` has its data values in the following way: `'25-10-2017 03:30'` which does not conform with datetime index. Now I tried to correct this date by using

```
file['Time valid (UTC)']=pd.to_datatime(file['Time valid (UTC)'],format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
```

However, the following errors pops up

```
     file['Time valid (UTC)']=pd.to_datatime(file['Time valid (UTC)'],format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_datatime'
```

Any idead about how to fix this or how to set the datetime correctly at once with `pd.DatetimeIndex`?

Comment: It is typo, `pd.to_datetime`, not `pd.to_datatime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct the function name to **pd.to_datetime()**

Comment: sorry my bad, thanks for the help